# How exactly does an inductor behave in a circuit after reaching its steady state?

Tags: electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction, inductance, short-circuits

I was solving this question in my coursebook and was not able to understand it conceptually. Though I did understand the mathematical approach to it.
[image: question]

Now I understand that when the rod is given an initial velocity towards right, due to its motion an EMF is induced across it. Current starts flowing until it reaches a steady state. However, once the current becomes constant, no potential difference exists and the current slowly starts dying out at which point the rod starts moving back to its mean position. Then the velocity is in the opposite direction and the 'polarity' of the induced EMF reverses and current starts flowing in the opposite direction.

My questions are-

1. Doesn't it take an infinite time for the inductor to reach its steady state (where it behaves as a connecting wire). So, wouldn't the rod move in the direction of its initial velocity forever?
2. What will happen once a steady current is achieved in the circuit? Will it be correct to say that since the potential difference across the ends of the rod is zero, the current wants to decrease to zero immediately, but the inductor only supports a slow decay of current?
3. Can we also say that the reason the circuit doesn't heat up due to short circuiting is because there is no actual battery in the circuit?

I tried asking my teacher but I couldn't get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: The reason the circuit doesn't heat up is that whenever we see anything that looks like a circuit diagram in a physics exercise, we assume ideal components unless the problem statement says otherwise. There is no resistor in the diagram, so nothing that could convert electrical energy to heat. Ideal wires and ideal inductors have no resistance. They dissipate no energy.

Comment: The emf generated withing the circuit is not constant and so there is no asymptotic behaviour. What assumption has to be made about the resistance of the circuit? As the rod slows down where does the kinetic energy go? The rod stops then what happens?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Indeed. And the eternal challenge for the physics student is decoding what idealization is intended. Realistic models of physical inductors can be quite elaborate, yet they are still idealizations.

Answer (score 0):

The restoring force in the system is not the current dying out, instead the current in the rod pushes the rod back due to Lorentz force, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Force_on_a_current-carrying_wire. Anyway, to answer your questions:

1. Once there is current in the rod, the magnetic field is pushing those moving particles to the left, slowing the rod down. This force is proportional to the current, and the inductor is keeping the current going, so the acceleration of the rod will only increase until it stops.
2. There is no steady state. If the rod was not allowed to move, then the inductor would simply keep the current going until consumed by the tiny resistance in the wires. However, there is still current going through the rod, so there is a force pushing it left, so it instead reverses direction and starts oscillating.
3. This isn't really a short circuit, due to the inductor. If there was simply a wire instead of the inductor, the current would grow very large very quickly, also stopping the rod quickly, dissipating it's initial kinetic energy as heat in the wires. However, the inductor in this case prevents the current from growing too large. We say that it has impedance, which is analogous to resistance for alternating current.